# Selenium PhantomJS in Python not running on ec2 instance

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-ec2, phantomjs

This is the code snippet of my python script. I am using PhantomJS 1.9.1 and python 2.7.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "http://***"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True

def test_one(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/"+datestring)
    driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("span.zoom_link").click();')
    targeturl = anchor_tag.get_attribute("src")
    datestring =datestring.replace('/','_')
    urllib.urlretrieve(targeturl, datestring+".jpg")
```

The code is running as expected in my mac os locally, but when I deploy the same script on ec2 cent os instance, its throwing the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "one.py", line 28, in test_one
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("span.zoom_link").click();')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 461, in execute_script
{'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: Message: Error Message => ''undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.querySelector("span.zoom_link").click()')'
caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"130","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:39740","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"sessionId\": \"fds\", \"args\": [], \"script\": \"document.querySelector(\\\"span.zoom_link\\\").click();\"}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/c1c222d0-1cb6-11e6-bd87-e5a4b311ba07/execute"}
```

Comment: Are you using the same version of `Selenium` and `PhantomJS` locally and on the remote machine?

Comment: Its my mistake, PhantomJS version is 1.9.1 in my ec2, when I changed it to 2.1.1, its working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using an *attribute selector*, i.e. change the `querySelector` from

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("span.zoom_link").click();')
```

to

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector(\'span[class="zoom_link"]\').click();')
```